# Convert values below a threshold into 1

Tags: r, if-statement

Let's say if I have the following data

```
x <- rnorm(100)
```

I want to create another column where where if `x` is equal to or greater than 0.2, give it a value of 1 or else 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can create the logical condition and wrap with `+`

```
xNew <- +(x >=0.2)
```

If we need a `data.frame`,

```
dat <- data.frame(x, xNew)
```

Or use `ifelse`

```
xNew <- ifelse(x >= 0.2, 1, 0)
```

Comment: converts TRUE or FALSE to an Integer -> either 0 for FALSE  or 1 for TRUE

Comment: @user1945827 The logical TRUE/FALSE gets coerced to binary 1/0 by using `+`

Comment: it's a rly neat way to turn the logical values into numeric. you can also use `as.numeric`

Comment: @hrbrmstr thnx ... worked out the as.numeric but couldn't see how the + worked (I found that minus returns -1s too!).

Comment: @user1945827 There are many options `(x >=0.2) + 0L` or `(x >=0.2)*1`

Comment: R's C underpinnings mean that `FALSE` == 0 and "anything else" == `TRUE`. Note that the `+` coercion is many orders of magnitude faster than `as.numeric`.

Comment: @hrbrmstr and `as.integer` is even faster (and makes the intent more obvious).

Answer (score 6):

You want to use an Heaviside function. You can find it in the `fbasics` package, for example.

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(100)
library(fBasics)
Heaviside(x, 0.2)
```

Comment: neat way. This has to be the solution.

Comment: nothing at all since it provides the result! But a mathematical appraoch is far neater than an IT one (and the function speaks by itself, a little bit more functional programming) :)

Comment: See my non-answer benchmark "answer". It's totally not what you want to do at all.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I can understand that.  Not any surprises here :-)

Answer (score 6):

Doing this for the benefit of the Colonel:

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(1492)
x <- rnorm(10000)

microbenchmark(asi=as.integer(x >= 0.2),
               asn=as.numeric(x >= 0.2),
               pls=+(x >=0.2),
               hsd=Heaviside(x, 0.2))

## Unit: microseconds
##  expr    min      lq      mean  median      uq      max neval cld
##   asi 18.351 20.7575  27.88867 22.4250 22.8695  598.206   100  a 
##   asn 23.710 25.9740  32.77422 29.2405 29.9860  340.234   100  a 
##   pls 17.989 20.2640  26.07038 22.6855 23.3020  320.443   100  a 
##   hsd 88.493 92.2145 148.17850 94.1935 95.5250 2831.695   100   b
```

Heaviside is totally *not* what you want to be doing if you care at all about performance. And, it's just doing:

```
function (x, a = 0) {
  result = (sign(x - a) + 1)/2
  result
}
```

anyway.

Comment: Comparing `+` with `as.numeric` is not a fair comparison. The former returns an `integer`.

Comment: So what happens when you wrap the fast code into your own `Heaviside` function? After all, nobody wants to litter their code base with unintelligible hacks, and functions are exactly intended to fix this. (EDIT: tried it. it’s almost on par with the fastest solution. That’s reassuring.)

Comment: How is `+()` unintelligible? _"Unary + and unary - return a numeric or complex vector. All attributes (including class) are preserved if there is no coercion: logical x is coerced to integer and names, dims and dimnames are preserved._" (from `help(+)`)